# "No such property" when refreshing project in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I have a groovy project in IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.1.5 based on gradle. I'm using groovy 2.4.4. My IDEA is set up to run gradle with gradle 4.0.2.

Gradle 'webclient' project refresh failed

> Error:No such property: from for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskOutputs$TaskOutputUnionFileCollection

Unfortunately, nothing in IntelliJ tells me where this error comes from. All I know is, from the package name, that it has to do with gradle. This IDE is seemingly really unhelpful. It either works, which is rarely, and when it doesn't work, doesn't give you much error reporting.

Comment: Try 2017.2.1 version, 2017.1 may not work properly with Gradle 4.x.

Comment: @CrazyCoder updated to 2017.2.1. Still, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around. If I add

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

To the top of my module's build.gradle

and run

```
./gradlew idea
```

It downloads my dependencies in to the right place (where, IDK, but it works - im guessing IDEA knows how to find my local ~/.gradle repo).

But refreshing the project from the UI still fails. It would be nice of IntelliJ told you what it's doing. I don't know why they want to hide everything it's doing, when the system is so brittle and breakable.

Comment: The suggestion of importing the project instead of using the idea plugin doesn't work. In fact, importing the project (yes, importing as a 'gradle' project), does not generate an '.iml' file. Moreover, the same error occurs, as describe din the original post. Thanks for the suggestion though. It seems IntelliJ is really broken here.

Comment: File a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the logs and a sample project to reproduce, no one has reported the exception you have yet, so it may be specific to your system/environment/project/etc.